# Не создается cookie на yii2

Tags: php, yii2, cookie

Создаю cookie на yii2

```
Yii::$app->response->cookies->add(new \yii\web\Cookie([
    'name' => 'likes',
    'value' => serialize($arr),                                                
]));
```

Если создать cookie через `setcookie`, то все работает! Помогите пожалуйста.))

Comment: Смотрите https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/541

Answer (score 1):

Не правильно, нужно так

```
$cookies = Yii::$app->response->cookies;

// добавление новой куки в HTTP-ответ
$cookies->add(new \yii\web\Cookie([
    'name' => 'language',
    'value' => 'zh-CN',
]));
```

Comment: все правильно ето один и тот же код, если би хорошо учил php, то би знал

Comment: @OlexijHavryshkiv а если бы ты не остроумничал, а сначала что-то пробовал, не писал бы того чего не знаешь!

Comment: Я уже много чего перепробовал не помагает! @Ricco381